# How to un-keyboard focus on TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I'm using [PromptTextBox](https://github.com/Grabacr07/MetroRadiance/blob/develop/source/MetroRadiance/Themes/Generic.PromptTextBox.xaml) that will show prompt text inside itself when `Text` is empty and `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` is false.

The problem is when I start new window, it automatically keyboard focus on the first TextBox so the prompt text isn't shown(but this behavior is acceptable).
If I want to un-keyboard focus I must click on another controls(e.g. click a Button, click on another TextBox), I can't click on blank space to un-keyboard focus.

I also test on normal TextBox, it's behavior is the same. so the question is:
How can I un-keyboard focus once I'd keyboard focused on TextBox by click on blank space?

Answer (score 0):

In the `MouseDown` event handler for the `'blank space'`, focus on some other control, if you have any. Or else, you need an invisible/out-of-view-bounds TextBox to focus on:

```
<blankSpaceControl>.MouseDown += ClearFocus;

void ClearFocus(object sender, MouseEventArgs me)
{
    <yourOtherFocusableControl>.Focus();
}
```

There is no other way. Focusing the Window itself will pass the focus on to the first focusable child control.

Comment: So, I need to add event to every controls that user may click on it to clear focus on TextBox? I have application that behave the way I want I've inspected it but I don't know how it achieve this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Keyboard.ClearFocus()

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.clearfocus.aspx

Comment: So, I need to add event to every controls that user may click on it to clear focus on TextBox? I have application that behave the way I want I've inspected it but I don't know how it achieve this behavior.